# Google Map App not working on Nexus 7

Tags: google-maps

I just wanted to ask if anyone experienced the same thing.
I wrote for testing purposes a little app for dealing with the google maps api.
I can run it perfectly on my Desire HD but not on my Nexus 7 , the logcat says that my Nexus cannot connect to the google servers due to a suspicious auth. error.
All I get is a white map...

But I am using the same fingerprint key for my Desire HD.

Anyone any idea?